# How to highlight text using ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK

Tags: asp.net, ocr, abbyy

I am using trial version of ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK for doing OCR of scanned images in asp.net application. I want to know how I can highlight text in output.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the coordinates of each word using export to xml and highlight the text using its coordinates on your side.

You can set the following parameters of the [processImage](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processImage/) method to make to disable any deskew (so the coordinates on the source images will be the same as in the exported PDF):

•   imageSource=scanner

•   correctSkew=false